# Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form. The file will not be sent

Tags: php, html

I am following along with a PHP tutorial, and am not able to get past this one problem:

`Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form. The file will not be sent.`

[Picture of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9vYd.png)

I have double checked to make sure all the files have permissions,
I have copy-pasted the exact code from the tutorial, and so far nothing has worked.
I've seen other similar questions, but none of their answers have worked either.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["ftrImg"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(isset($_POST["sbtImg"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["ftrImg"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}
?>
    
    <form action="" formMethod="POST" formEncType="multipart/form-data">
        
        Upload your picture:
        <input type="file" name="ftrImg" id="ftrImg">
        <input type="submit" value="upload" name="sbtImg">
        
    </form>
```

Replacing `method` and `enctype` with `formMethod` and `formEncType` cleared up the error 500 that I was getting but didn't solve this problem.
FYI I'm using XAMPP server on linux.

The thing I don't get about the warning is that I *do* have `method` and `enctype` on the form.

Comment: `<form action="" formMethod="POST" formEncType="multipart/form-data">` is incorrect, that should be `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` ~ you can omit the action attribute if targeting the same page

Comment: My guess is that by modifying those attributes of the form you changed the nature of the form so that it would no longer issue a POST request and would fall back to the default of GET most probably - thus the PHP logic using `isset( $_POST["sbtImg"] )` was not triggered (?) and the error not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

> `<form action="" formMethod="POST" formEncType="multipart/form-data">`
> is incorrect, that should be `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` ~ you can omit the action attribute if
> targeting the same page

[Professor Adronsius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3603681/professor-abronsius)'s comment solved the problem.
I am now able to upload files successfully. Thanks!

*By the way, even when I separate the PHP into another file, it works - which is strange because it never used to work either.
Its amazing how having someone else look at your code makes it work.*